# show breadcrumb on child menu and grandchild menu wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

so I have a menu like this:

```
-inspiration<parent page>
 -- healt<child page>
  --Medicine<grandchild page>
  --Teraphy<grandchild page>
 -- Mind<child page>
  --Consult<grandchild page>
  --Psych<grandchild page>
```

I want to show breadcrumbs only when I open the child page and grand childpage.

For example, when I open "inpiration" page I dont want to show any breadcrumbs.
But when I open "healt" page, I want to have breadcrumbs with output "healt" and "medicine".

In `base.php` I have code like this :

```
<div class="second-menu">
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <?php

      $args = array(
      'child_of' => get_top_ancestor_id(),
      'title_li' => ''
      );

     ?>

      <?php wp_list_pages($args); ?>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

And in my `function.php` I have code like this:

```
function get_top_ancestor_id() {

    global $post;

    if ($post->post_parent) {
        $ancestors = array_reverse(get_post_ancestors($post->ID));
        return $ancestors[0];

    }

    return $post->ID;

}
```

But after I refresh the child page ("healt" page), the output of breadcrumbs is like this:

```
-healt
--Medicine
--Teraphy
-Mind
--Consult
--Psych
```

What I want is to make it just:

```
--Medicine
--Teraphy
```

I think because the "healt" page is seen as child page. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The function

```
wp_list_pages
```

Will display 'only the sub-pages of a single page by ID' so when you are in the 'Health page' this function

```
$ancestors = array_reverse(get_post_ancestors($post->ID));
```

Will return the childs of 'inspiration' because you are returning 'Medicine' parent page ID. Maybe you could try to print the childs only instead, like

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_parent = %s AND post_type = %s", $post->ID, 'page' ) );
if ( $result ) {
    foreach ( $result as $page ) {
        array_push( $childs, $page->ID );
    }
}
```

Something like that.